# How can we Concatenate vector elements before specific separator and make new vector in Rust

Tags: string, vector, rust, calculator

I want to to concatenate all 3 elements of vector named 'items' before operator and two elements after operator like this 
["2","2","2","+","2","3"] to ["222","+","23"]

```
let items = vec!["2","2","2","+","2","3"];
let mut new_items = vec![];
for i in 0..items.len() {
    new_items.insert(i, items[i].to_owned());
}
let mut count = 0;
for i in 0..new_items.len() {
    if new_items[i] == "+" {}
    else {            
        new_items[i] = format!("{}{}",new_items[i],new_items[i+1]);
        new_items.remove(i+1);
        count += 1;
    }
}

println!("{:?}",new_items);
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: failed to build the logic to iterate through vector to get the desired result need help to  find the logic. i have ["2","2","2","+","2","3"]  vector and wants transform like this ["222","+","23"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following:

```
pub fn main() {
    let items = vec!["2","2","2","+","2","3"];

    // use a number variable to capture the operand
    let mut number = String::new();
    let mut new_items = vec![];

    for s in items {
        if s == "+" {
            // if found an operator, push and clear the current operand and operator
            new_items.push(number.drain(..).collect());
            new_items.push(s.to_owned());
        } else {
            number.push_str(s);
        }
    }

    if !number.is_empty() {
        new_items.push(number);
    }

    println!("{:?}", new_items);
}
```

[the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf0e4a92e97ed50460a54dc251eea81b).

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb715884ea5096a58747eb5b09dca95d  

'cannot infer type for `T`' error after integrating with my code of simple expression calculator kindly check

Comment: `let mut new_items: Vec<String> = vec![];`? But it looks you have more compile error to fix.

Comment: Yeah getting the same error after type annotation please guide me

Comment: Remove line 5. It is never used, so there isn't a type given. If you had given type annotations it would've worked. Doing that gives another error about ownership, I'd recommend you read the rust book to learn about that.